# why only last item in a given object is targeted?

Tags: jquery

[image]

Above shows the template containing objects as shown in the console tab in firebug

```
console.debug(mimicTemplate);

//mimicTemplate is a template containing two or more similar objects.

$.each(mimicTemplate, function (index, value) {

//only last object is targetted                             
$(value).find(config.selectors.elementId).css('background-color', '#c8e6c9');
$(value).find(config.selectors.elementId).data('id', attachment[i].fileId);
});
```

expected, each object in the template should be targetted

Tried:

```
    $.each(mimicTemplate, function (index, value) {
    console.debug(attachment[i].fileId);
    $(value).parent().children().toggle().find(config.selectors.elementId).css('background-color', '#c8e6c9');
    $(value).parent().children().toggle().find(config.selectors.elementId).data('id', attachment[i].fileId);
});


$(value).parent().children().toggle() targets each elements, but `.data('id', attachment[i].fileId); is replaced with last value for each element`.

console.debug(attachment[i].fileId); shows each id correctly. Only when it comes to assigning the value to the data attribbute, it gets the last item and replaces all elments.
```

Comment: what is config.selectors.elementId????

Comment: value is class or id of some element ? same question for config.selectors.elementId ? If I am not wrong, try ...find("#"+config.selectors.elementId)

Comment: config.selectors.elementId is my way of getting selector like $(['data-elementId])

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are too many unknowns in what is shown